# change form method when element is on stage. jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to change form method after elemets are on stage. Elements shows in dependence what is typed in input field.

When on stage are elements called ".wordHint" i want to hve get method else post method. I have done it with this:

```
$("#input_text").keydown(function(e) {

  if($(".wordHint").length==0)
    $("#searchForm").attr("method", "post");
  else
    $("#searchForm").attr("method", "get");
});
```

it works but it is always one step back.

example type:
"ab" and it should be method post, after put one more letter like "c" it should be get but it is not. When i put another letter like "d" it change to get.

Any ideas how to do it right?
I have alredy tryied with keyup, on and work same.

Comment: Did you try with `.keyup()` ?

Comment: yes but it works same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keydown` triggers when you push the button, but at this moment input value does not changed yet. Try to use `keyup` event

Comment: same effect i alredy tryied it. after puts abc element with calss .wordHint is created and then it should change to get but it chane afyer put one more letter

Comment: I think `if($(".wordHint").length==0)` is the reason. Can you post html and rest of js code?

Comment: Yes i also think that. The elements .wordHint are creating dynamically when typping via php. i think that after press key that element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Maybe before try to change form method you need to run function that checks state of `.wordHint` element and if it needs create it.

Comment: Right now i'm sure that element doesn't exist, i have tryied call timer with 100ms and it works... but now i have to think how to resolve it normally

Comment: You need to synchronize `keypress` function and function that creates `.wordHint`. For example `wordHintCreatorFunction(); if($(".wordHint").length==0) {}...`

Answer (score 1):

Try `.keypress()`, it's similar to `keydown()`, but without triggering on non-printing keys such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and <kbd>del</kbd>.